# Port iPhone (OpenGL / C++) game to Android

Tags: iphone, android, port

I need to port an iPhone game developed in OpenGL and C++ (with very little objective c code) to Android.

Is there any resource I could read to get started?

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html as a starter but I'm afraid I'm with WarrenFaith on this as it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Read the FAQ. Tis site is also to ask about: "software tools commonly used by programmers", "matters that are unique to the programming profession". I think my question is valid, and it has not been asked here before.

Answer (score 4):

You want to check out these two Google IO presentations:

1. Writing Real Time Games for Android Redux (2010)
   http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-real-time-games-android.html
2. Writing Real Time Games for Android (2009)
   http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/WritingRealTimeGamesAndroid.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the NeHe tutorials to get started with OpenGL on Android. http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the NDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

this book is slightly outdated but should get you going [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00440E0JY/ref=kinw_myk_ro_title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00440E0JY)

Answer (score -2):

You can use Unity for Android to [Port iPhone games to Android](http://geeknizer.com/port-iphone-ios-games-to-android/)